# H2 Database always gets corrupted

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, h2

Within a java spring-boot service (using Gradle), which provides a REST API to get data from the h2 database, I'll face the problem that the database always gets corrupted after a period of time. Sadly I'm not able to reconstruct the process in which the database gets corrupted. It always happens in "production".

A client uses the endpoints / API to get several data. The service queries the data out of the database and returns it to the client.

Further, a scheduled job is exectued within the context which gets data from another service and inserts this data to the h2 database.

Exceptions I face when database is corrupted

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=2 SYS"
General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=2 SYS" [50000-196]
```

and

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Datei fehlerhaft beim Lesen des Datensatzes: "index not found 1020". Mögliche Lösung: Recovery Werkzeug verwenden
File corrupted while reading record: "index not found 1020". Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-194]
```

The h2 connection settings in the application.properties file:

```
dataBaseFile=./db/file.db
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:${dataBaseFile};DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=30000;MVCC=TRUE;MV_STORE=FALSE;LOCK_MODE=0
spring.datasource.username=yyyy
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console
```

Please let me know if you need further information as I currently don't know what exactly leads to this problem.

Update #1
Full exception

```
2018-01-23 13:40:13.687  INFO [MyService,,,] 6172 --- [main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-01-23 13:40:18.359 ERROR [MyService,,,] 6172 --- [main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Datei fehlerhaft beim Lesen des Datensatzes: "index not found 358". Mögliche Lösung: Recovery Werkzeug verwenden
File corrupted while reading record: "index not found 358". Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-194]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.getPage(PageStore.java:769) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.getPage(PageDataIndex.java:232) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.index.PageDataNode.getNextPage(PageDataNode.java:232) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.index.PageDataLeaf.getNextPage(PageDataLeaf.java:397) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.index.PageDataCursor.nextRow(PageDataCursor.java:94) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.index.PageDataCursor.next(PageDataCursor.java:52) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addIndex(RegularTable.java:273) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:748) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:276) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:270) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:64) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:176) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:154) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:354) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:116) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) [spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) [spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) [spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at de.ica.tms.ka.etims.MessageServiceApplication.main(MessageServiceApplication.java:25) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [MyService-2.5.4-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [MyService-2.5.4-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [MyService-2.5.4-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [MyService-2.5.4-RELEASE.jar:na]

2018-01-23 13:40:18.374  WARN [MyService,,,] 6172 --- [main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2018-01-23 13:40:18.390  INFO [MyService,,,] 6172 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2018-01-23 13:40:18.452  WARN [MyService,,,] 6172 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException)
2018-01-23 13:40:18.484 ERROR [MyService,,,] 6172 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at de.ica.tms.ka.etims.MessageServiceApplication.main(MessageServiceApplication.java:25) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [MyService-2.5.4-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [MyService-2.5.4-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [MyService-2.5.4-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [MyService-2.5.4-RELEASE.jar:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

EDIT

I have investigated older log files and found following error(s) (timeout on locking table) before the DB gets in corrupted state and runs into the other exceptions. Maybe this is the root cause?

```
2018-01-19 14:57:28.843 ERROR [MyService,2e06f077ff5d3a94,2e06f077ff5d3a94,false] 3432 --- [http-nio-8091-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Zeitüberschreitung beim Versuch die Tabelle "TXBASETYPE_0" zu sperren
Timeout trying to lock table "TXBASETYPE_0"; SQL statement:
select txamltype0_.hjid as hjid1_117_0_, txamltype0_1_.txbase_txbasetype_0_hjid as txbase_t2_117_0_, txamltype0_.amlisteempfaengerid as amlistee1_97_0_, txamltype0_.amlistenummer as amlisten2_97_0_, txamltype0_.amlistesenderid as amlistes3_97_0_, txamltype0_.amlistezeitstempelitem as amlistez4_97_0_, iontxheade1_.hjid as hjid1_18_1_, iontxheade1_.device_id as device_i2_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transauftrag as transauf3_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transempfaengerid as transemp4_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transempfaengerrolle as transemp5_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transsignatur as transsig6_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transsignaturtyp as transsig7_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transsignaturzertifikat as transsig8_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transstatus as transsta9_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transtransaktionid_iontxhead_1 as transtr14_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transtransaktionstyp as transtr10_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transtransaktionszeitpunktit_0 as transtr11_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transversion as transve12_18_1_, iontxheade1_.transwiederholungszaehler as transwi13_18_1_, iontxheade1_1_.symmetrickeylist_txsymkeylty_0 as symmetri2_272_1_, iontxheade1_2_.symmetrickey_txsymkeyacktype_0 as symmetri2_271_1_, iontxheade1_3_.cvcertificatelist_txcvcertlt_0 as cvcertif2_124_1_, case when iontxheade1_1_.hjid is not null then 1 when iontxheade1_2_.hjid is not null then 2 when iontxheade1_3_.hjid is not null then 3 when iontxheade1_.hjid is not null then 0 end as clazz_1_, iontransak2_.hjid as hjid1_17_2_, iontransak2_.transsenderid as transsen2_17_2_, iontransak2_.transsenderrolle as transsen3_17_2_, iontransak2_.transsequenznummer as transseq4_17_2_, txsymkeylt3_.hjid as hjid1_66_3_, txcvcertlt4_.hjid as hjid1_9_4_, txsymkeyac5_.hjid as hjid1_65_5_, txsymkeyac5_.samid as samid2_65_5_, txsymkeyac5_.sequencenumber as sequence3_65_5_ from txamltype_0 txamltype0_ inner join txbasetype_0 txamltype0_1_ on txamltype0_.hjid=txamltype0_1_.hjid left outer join iontxheadertype_0 iontxheade1_ on txamltype0_1_.txbase_txbasetype_0_hjid=iontxheade1_.hjid left outer join txsymkeyltype iontxheade1_1_ on iontxheade1_.hjid=iontxheade1_1_.hjid left outer join txsymkeyacktype iontxheade1_2_ on iontxheade1_.hjid=iontxheade1_2_.hjid left outer join txcvcertltype iontxheade1_3_ on iontxheade1_.hjid=iontxheade1_3_.hjid left outer join iontransaktionidtype_0 iontransak2_ on iontxheade1_.transtransaktionid_iontxhead_1=iontransak2_.hjid left outer join symmetrickeylist txsymkeylt3_ on iontxheade1_1_.symmetrickeylist_txsymkeylty_0=txsymkeylt3_.hjid left outer join cvcertificatelist txcvcertlt4_ on iontxheade1_3_.cvcertificatelist_txcvcertlt_0=txcvcertlt4_.hjid left outer join symmetrickey_0 txsymkeyac5_ on iontxheade1_2_.symmetrickey_txsymkeyacktype_0=txsymkeyac5_.hjid where txamltype0_.hjid=? [50200-194]
2018-01-19 14:57:28.874 ERROR [MyService,,,] 3432 --- [http-nio-8091-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.PessimisticLockingFailureException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: could not extract ResultSet] with
```

Comment: can you show your pom.xml please

Comment: As the initial developer used gradle there is no pom.xml (afaik pom.xml is used by Maven). I can provide the build.gradle and settings.gradle (contains only one line)

Comment: Just check if you dont mix/use multiple versions of H2. This could be one of the reasons.

Comment: In the dependencies block of the build.gradle file I only find one entry containing a reference to h2: _runtime('com.h2database:h2')_ The gradle browser window shows under dependencies the entry: _com.h2database:h2:1.4.194 (Runtime)_

Comment: I'm guessing that full stack traces would be more useful to someone familiar with the h2 code base rather than just the first line of the exception

Comment: Thanks. Added full stack traces

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that a connection is not being returned to the pool? You should always close a `java.sql.Connection` or a `org.hibernate.Session` in a `finally { ... }` block. Perhaps this is what's causing the lock timeout because there's another transaction blocking which will never be committed (maybe an error occurred on another thread but the connection/hibernate session wasn't closed)

Comment: Thanks for the input. As far as I can see the sessions are not managed manually. As Im not familiar with the spring framework I assume that the entitys, which are represented by class definitions / objects, are handled by the hibernate automatically. As i can see there is no place where a session is opened manually.

Comment: I've not used spring boot and hibernate together so forgive my lack of knowledge there. It makes sense that there is a [servlet filter](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpFilter.html) that can return open connections back to the pool at the end of a request/response. Is it possible that your application is trying to do use this functionality outside of a http request/response? (eg a scheduled task). In this case I don't think the connection will get returned to the pool automatically, you'll need to explicitly clean up after your "non request" actions

Answer (score 0):

You have used `LOCK_MODE=0`. That's documented to be very dangerous in the [FAQ](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#reliable), "dangerous features are: ... LOCK_MODE 0 ...".

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately I've tried both without success. As there are two threads accessing the database (The scheduled Job updating the data and the REST API providing data from the database) I'm wondering if it would help to use the parameter `MULTI_THREADED`